Inverse after Khatri-Rao product vs. Khatri-Rao product after inverse
Given two matrices $A_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times k}$ and $A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times k}$ of full column rank. The 2-norms of columns of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are equal to 1. $k$ is fixed and $k \ll p,q$, where $p,q \to \infty$.
Let "$*$" denote Khatri-Rao product. Define $B_1 = A_1 (A_1^\top A_1)^{-1}$ and $B_2 = A_2 (A_2^\top A_2)^{-1}$. And define $B = B_1 * B_2$.
Now define $A = A_1 * A_2$, I am interested in whether the difference between $B$ and $A(A^\top A)^{-1}$ goes to $0$ as $p,q$ go to infinity. If not, what conditions on $A_1$ and $A_2$ do we need to make this true, and what is the order of the difference, i.e. what is $f(p,q)$ such that
$$
\|B - A(A^\top A)^{-1}\|_2 = \mathcal{O}\left(f(p,q)\right). 
$$
One can easily show that they are equivalent when $A_1$ and $A_2$ are orthonormal since $B = B_1 *B_2 = A_1 * A_2$ and
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
A &= (A_1 * A_2) \left( (A_1 * A_2)^\top (A_1 * A_2) \right)^{-1} \\ 
&= (A_1 * A_2) \left( (A_1^\top A_1) \circ (A_2^\top A_2) \right)^{-1} \\ 
&= A_1 * A_2 = B, 
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\circ$ is Hadamard product.
In the case where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not orthonormal, consider the simplified case $k=2$. Let $e_1 = (1,0)^\top$ and $e_2 = (0,1)^\top$. We have
\begin{align*} 
B &= B_1 * B_2 \\ 
&= \left(A_1 (A_1^\top A_1)^{-1}\right) * \left(A_2 (A_2 \top A_2)^{-1} \right) \\ 
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
\left(A_1 (A_1^\top A_1)^{-1} e_1\right) \otimes \left(A_2 (A_2 \top A_2)^{-1} e_1 \right) & \left(A_1 (A_1^\top A_1)^{-1} e_2\right) \otimes \left(A_2 (A_2 \top A_2)^{-1} e_2 \right)
\end{bmatrix}, 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*} 
A(A^\top A)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} (A_1 e_1) \otimes (A_2 e_1) & (A_1 e_2) \otimes (A_2 e_2) \end{bmatrix} \left( (A_2^\top A_2) \circ (A_1^\top A_1) \right)^{-1}. 
\end{align*}
I could compute the exact inverse using the formula for 2 by 2 matrix but the result becomes unwieldy and may not be easily generalized to the case where $k > 2$.
Regarding the conditions on $A_1$ and $A_2$ when they are not orthonormal, intuitively, the number of non-zero entries of each column should increase in $p$ and $q$ or else the problem will reduce to fixed $p$ and $q$. What if the entry of $A_1$ is $\mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{p})$ and $A_2$ is $\mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{q})$ so that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are "dense"? In this case, my simulation suggests the difference converges to $0$ as $p,q$ go to infinity. Also, I feel the difference will depend on the correlations between columns since it will affect the behavior of the inverse of "Gram matrix".
Can anyone provide hints or insights on how to derive these results more neatly? Are there any standard techniques or theoretical results I could use to analyze the behavior of this difference?

$
\def\bx{\boxtimes} \def\h{\odot} \def\k{\otimes}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)} \def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1\right\rbrace}
$Note that $B_k$ is the transpose of the pseudoinverse of $A_k,,$ e.g.
$${ B_1=\LR{A_1^{\bf+}}^T=A_1\LR{A_1^TA_1}^{-1}}$$
and the following identities
$$\eqalign{
&\LR{E\bx F}^{\bf+} ;&=; \LR{E^TE\h F^TF}^{\bf+} \LR{E\bx F}^T \
&\LR{XE}\bx\LR{YF} ;&=; \LR{X\k Y} \LR{E\bx F} \
&\LR{XE}\h\LR{YF} ;&=; \LR{X^T\bx Y^T}^T \LR{E\bx F} \
}$$
where $\CR{\bx,\k,\h}$ denote the $\CR{{\sf Khatri!-!Rao, Kronecker, Hadamard}}$ products.
